# Microscale Experimentation vs. Preparative Synthesis during drug development

Tags: organic-chemistry, drugs

I'm trying to understand the drug development stages, techniques and procedures. My understanding on the subject:

**Microscale experimentation**

- Is used on early stages to find compounds reacting with some target
  proteins/whatever
- Is done on a very small scale (< 1mg) since most of
  the compounds are not going to react with the target
- Techniques: Combinatorial Chemistry

**Preparative Synthesis**

- Is done on later stages when we found a number of potentially useful compounds
- Is used to synthesise compounds in larger quantities (5-200mg) for further testing and possible conversions to other compounds with better characteristics (e.g. lower toxicity or better distribution). We need larger quantities because we will conduct a lot of experiments with these compounds down the road (including microscale experimentation?)
- Techniques: High-Throughput Chemistry

Could someone please correct and possibly extend my explanation?

Comment: What exactly do you want clarification about? You seem pretty clear on the subject to me.

Comment: I didn't know if I was understanding all the details correctly, wanted to confirm my vision. If you're saying that everything is okay, then I'm happy :)